# issues connecting java to sqlite

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I've read through many of the threads posted on this topic but none of them have been able to solve my problem. I use a mac and I'm trying to connect a java project to sqlite and I'm having some problems.  I have successfully connected to mysql to java.  To connect mysql I had to add a mysql.jar file to my system/library/java/extensions folder. Once I did that it was smooth sailing. I have not been to fortunate with sqlite. I went to xerial and tried to use their sqlite jdbc but doing that created a ton of other errors when I ran it.

Is there a simple method and an easy jar I can use to connect java to sqlite? something like the process I described above for mysql?

If not can anyone offer me some help.

Thanks for your help!

here is the code I used:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SQLiteJDBC
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
// load the sqlite-JDBC driver using the current class loader
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

Connection connection = null;
try
{
  // create a database connection
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db");
  Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
  statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  // set timeout to 30 sec.

  statement.executeUpdate("drop table if exists person");
  statement.executeUpdate("create table person (id integer, name string)");
  statement.executeUpdate("insert into person values(1, 'leo')");
  statement.executeUpdate("insert into person values(2, 'yui')");
  ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from person");
  while(rs.next())
  {
    // read the result set
    System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString("name"));
    System.out.println("id = " + rs.getInt("id"));
  }
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
  // if the error message is "out of memory", 
  // it probably means no database file is found
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
finally
{
  try
  {
    if(connection != null)
      connection.close();
  }
  catch(SQLException e)
  {
    // connection close failed.
    System.err.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

these are the errors I received when using the xerial jar:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sqlite/NativeDB
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
>     at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
>     at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
>     at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:200)
>     at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.extractAndLoadLibraryFile(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:148)
>     at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:249)
>     at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:65)
>     at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.load(NativeDB.java:53)
>     at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:136)
>     at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.(CoreConnection.java:66)
>     at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.(JDBC3Connection.java:21)
>     at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
>     at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.(SQLiteConnection.java:44)
>     at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:113)
>     at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:87)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
>     at SQLiteJDBC.main(SQLiteJDBC.java:18)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.NativeDB
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>     ... 21 more

these are the errors I received without the xerial jar:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
>     at SQLiteJDBC.main(SQLiteJDBC.java:12)

Comment: are you using jars from here https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads ?

Comment: yes.  I tried using sqlite-jdbc4-3.8.2-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you already found the answer but just in case. I had the same issue, also with my mac, and I found the solution in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106550/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-sqlite-nativedb). In summary, that jar is not suitable for mac, but you can use sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar from the same site. I hope I have been helpful.

Comment: I did eventually get it working but I found a similar solution as the one posed in the link you provided.  Thanks for the follow up!